# Duplicate lines that included same strings after /film/

Tags: bash, shell, duplicate

Explaining is hard I want to start with example. Please see the Bold text.

I have very long list like the following list :

```
http://dl3/film/**Daylights.End**.3*******************
http://dl45/film/**The.Wild.Life**.720***************
http://dl45/film/**The.Wild.Life**.10***************
http://dl3.pw/film/T**he.Wild.Life**.2*******************
http://dl45/film/**Daylights.End**.2*******************
```

I want to find all Duplicate lines that included same strings after `/film/`, but I don’t want to search the line to the end, the search should look for duplicate strings just like 10 or 20 characters after `/film/`

- The strings after `/film/` are different.
- The method should search a list with like 5 thousand line and find all duplicate line and maybe after founding delete, cut, copy or mark One or Two of them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here's a start: `cat long-list |grep -Eo '/film/.{15}' |sort |uniq --repeated`. If this isn't what you want, please explain in more detail.

Comment: Are the * significant, especially between T**he.Wi and **The.Wi ? Would terminating near *.number* be reliable?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sed -n 's/^/@/' > newfile
```

or

```
sed -ni 's/^/@/'
```

Both commands are inserting an `@` at the beginning every libe of your last command.

Answer (score -1):

nice, command output for

cat long-list |grep -Eo '/film/.{15}' |sort |uniq --repeated

is a list that contain all duplicate names.
now how can i mark all duplicate line with something like a @ in start line?

Comment: You copied my comment into an answer and presented it as your own. Also, don't put questions in the 'answer' section. Ask a new question.